# sencha touch application issue with chrome 65 update

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-chrome, extjs, hybrid

After updating Chrome to chrome version 65 my application have started behaving abruptly. Navigation is not working properly between screens. It was working fine for last Chrome version 60.

If anyone faced similar kind of issue please help.

Comment: Can you provide code which isn't working anymore? If you get any errors, could you include them in your question please.

Comment: I have a controller for dashboard screen which gets called first time when i reach to dashboard screen after login but once i navigate to some other screen and come back to dashboard controller is not getting called. It was working fine till chrome version 60. No error is coming as such.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue with sencha.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357047/after-update-the-android-chrome-version-65-application-does-not-works-sencha-t?noredirect=1#comment85787085_49357047

Comment: Did you find any way around for this issue?

Comment: check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357047/after-update-the-android-chrome-version-65-application-does-not-works-sencha-t?noredirect=1#comment85787085_49357047

Comment: It helped. I have disabled navigation animation using below code.   layout: {
                        type: 'card',
                        animation: false
                    }

Comment: Though i tested my app in chrome beta version 67 and issue has been fixed in same.